# Identifying points located near to a polygons boundary

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I am trying to identify all points (postcodes in my case) that are located near to the coastline of the UK (i.e., a polygon). I am using R to process this.

I downloaded the geographical outline of United Kingdom from [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) as a shapefile. A list of all postcodes for the UK were accessed from the ONS [here](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::ons-postcode-directory-february-2022/about). Please note that the latter file is very large (211MB zipped).

To begin, I loaded in both files into R, and then convert them to the same coordinate reference system (OSGB1936; 27700). For the polygon of the UK, I convert this to lines that represent the boundary/coastline (note that while Northern Ireland shares a common boundary with Ireland, I will subset any postcodes erroneously matched as near the coastline by lat/long later). I then convert the points into spatial points.

```
# Load libraries
library(sf)
library(data.table)

# Load data
uk_shp <- read_sf("./GBR_adm/GBR_adm0.shp") # Load UK shapefile (ignore the download file says GBR, it is UK)
uk_shp <- st_transform(uk_shp, crs = 27700) # Convert to co-ordinate reference system (CRS) that allow buffers in correct units later (note: 4326 is World CRS)
uk_coast <- st_cast(uk_shp,"MULTILINESTRING") # Convert polygon to a line (i.e., coastline)

# Load in postcodes
pcd <- fread("./ONSPD_FEB_2022_UK/Data/ONSPD_FEB_2022_UK.csv") # Load all postcodes for Great Britain - this is a very large file so I also create a single 
pcd <- pcd[, c(1:3, 43:44)] # Drop unnecessary information/columns to save memory

# Convert to spatial points data frame
pcd_sp <- pcd %>% # For object of postcodes
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat")) %>% # Define as spatial object and identify which columns tell us the position of points
  st_set_crs(27700) # Set CRS
```

I originally thought the most efficient approach to take would be to define what a coastal region is (here defined as within 5km of the coastline), create a buffer to represent that around the coastline, and then use a point-in-polygon function to select all points within the buffers. However, the code below had not finished running overnight which probably suggests that it was the incorrect approach and I an unsure why it is taking so long.

```
uk_coast <- st_buffer(uk_coast, 5000) # Create 5km buffer
pcd_coastal <- st_intersection(uk_buf, pcd_sp) # Point-in-polygon (i.e., keep only the postcodes that are located in the buffer region)
```

So I changed my approach to calculate the straight-line distance of each point to the nearest coastline. In running the code below, it gives incorrect distances. For example below, I select one postcode (AB12 4XP) which is located ~2.6km from the coastline, however the code below gives ~82km which is very wrong. I had tried st_nearest_feature() but could not get it to work (it may do, but was beyond my attempts).

```
test <- pcd_sp[pcd_sp$pcd == "AB124XP",] # Subset test postcode
dist <- st_distance(test, uk_coast, by_element = TRUE, which = "Euclidean") # Calculate distance
```

I am unsure how to proceed from here - I don't think it is the wrong CRS. It might be that the multilinestring conversion is causing problems. Does anyone have suggestions what to do?

Comment: You probably want to set up some indexes, so a different format and may be a different program may help - look at PostGIS for storage and QGis for the analysis

Comment: Hi! Two points: 1) if you need to identify the points that lay close to the boundary you just need to run `st_intersects` instead of `st_intersection`; 2) I think that `st_contains(uk_buf, pcd_sp)` is much faster than all the other approaches since, I think, that function creates an index over the points data which is much more efficient than creating an index over the polygon data.

Comment: Have you tried plotting that point that you think is 2.6km from the coastline to see how it might thought to be 82km? AB12 4XP (according to https://postcodebyaddress.co.uk/ab124xp, its POINT (391621 796921)) gives me a distance of 1.938 km to `uk_coast`....

Comment: On my (10 year old) machine it takes 30s to compute 10,000 distances (from random points in the bounding box of the coast) to the coast using `st_distance(pts, uk_coast)`. Whenever doing something that might take a while, test on subsets and extrapolate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sf` has an `st_is_within_distance` function that can test if points are within a distance of a line. My test data is 10,000 random points in the bounding box of the UK shape, and the UK shape in OSGB grid coordinates.

```
> system.time({indist = st_is_within_distance(uk_coast, pts, dist=5000)})
   user  system elapsed 
 30.907   0.003  30.928
```

But this isn't building a spatial index. The docs say that it does build a spatial index if the coordinates are "geographic" and the flag for using spherical geometry is set. I don't understand why it can't build one for cartesian coordinates, but lets see how much faster it is...

Transform takes no time at all:

```
> ukLL = st_transform(uk_coast, 4326)
> ptsLL = st_transform(pts, 4326)
```

Then test...

```
 system.time({indistLL = st_is_within_distance(ukLL, ptsLL, dist=5000)})
   user  system elapsed 
  1.405   0.000   1.404
```

Just over a second. Any difference between the two? Let's see:

```
> setdiff(indistLL[[1]], indist[[1]])
[1] 3123
> setdiff(indist[[1]], indistLL[[1]])
integer(0)
```

So point 3123 is in the set using lat-long, but not the set using OSGB. There's nothing in OSGB that isn't in the lat-long set.

Quick plot to show the selected points:

```
> plot(uk_coast$geometry)
> plot(pts$geometry[indistLL[[1]]], add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked well - it was the nod to convert to WGS4326 that did the trick (in my case when converting pcd to pcd_sp, setting the CRS to 4326 then and not converting the shapefile earlier. Your code then worked a treat, thank you

Comment: Its *EPSG* 4326, (which *uses* WGS 84). EPSG is the authority on all coordinate systems, and publishes the list of EPSG codes and what they mean. WGS is "World Geodetic Survey" and usually refers to a particular approximate ellipsoidal shape of the earth. EPSG code 4326 is the standard lat-long coordinate system used by GPS, and WGS84 is one component of it.